# When enter http://my_server_IP_address don't see Apache HTTP server default page

Tags: linux, centos, ip, webserver, apache-httpd

I just launch a VPS instance use CentOS 7 x64. I follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7) for installing **Apache HTTP Server**

```
sudo yum install httpd
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

but when I use my browser (at client- my laptop) go to

```
http://my_server_IP_address/
```

**I don't see Apache HTTP Server's default welcome page.**

I stuck at here, please help me!

Comment: What do you see??

Comment: I open Mozilla Firefox browser in my laptop, go to `http://104.156.229.26`, nothing happen, no webpage/blank page display.

Comment: You should try using something like Mozilla Firebug to track what is happening when you send an HTTP request and output the results..

Comment: my browser really cannot connect Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: Ok and what does your logs say?

Comment: This is the content of file `/var/log/httpd/error_log`: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/e3897e9071a0147945928e9f7ff93707   File `/var/log/httpd/access_log` is empty

Answer (score 0):

I am unlucky when read a [not complete tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7).

After read an other tutorial:
http://www.guru99.com/what-is-apache-how-to-install-it.html

I type:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then go to

```
http://my_server_ip_address/
```

It works.